# Can't open a jQuery Dialog on "click" event

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, events, click, jquery-ui-dialog

I got a small issue here.

I have a button in a form (this is not a submit button). I want to click this button, check a value in my form and if this value is empty, open a Dialog bow a previously declare.

The issue is : the Dialog element doesn't want to be open.

So I ran some tests :
- I put the Dialog open outside the click event, it's ok
- I put an alert instead of the Dialog open, it's ok too

So this is my HTML :

```
<div id="popup_archive" style="display:none">
    Veuillez saisir un temps effectif pour cette tâche avant son archivage.<br />
    <input type="text" id="archive_temps_reel" />
</div>

...

<input type="text" size="50" name="temps_reel" />

...

<input id="btn_archiver" type="button" value="Archiver" class="a_bouton a_bouton_gris" />
```

And the jQuery one :

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    // on click btn_archiver
    $("#btn_archiver").click( function () {
        if($('input[name="temps_reel"]').val() == '')
        {
            alert("coco");
            $("#popup_archive").dialog("open");
        }
    });

    // define popup_archive
    $("#popup_archive").dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        modal: true,
        title: "Archivage"
    });

});
```

Anyone can help me ?
Thank you !

Comment: Works for me: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/didierg/LmZE4). Are you sure you don't get any error message in the console. Any other code that might prevent it from working ?

Comment: [Seems to work](http://jsfiddle.net/salman/QBZ8Q/)

Comment: Hum seems to work with Safari, Opera, but not with my Firefox 10.0.2, don't know why ... Works for my coworker with 10.0.2 ... Ok, I am the issue !

Comment: Try refreshing your browser's cache.

Comment: Ok I found the "bug". I uninstalled the jQuerify extension for FireBug, and my popup is ok. Don't know why ... Thanks for your answer, really helps me !

Comment: Why don't you post your last comment as an answer and then accept it. It would look better if this problem had an accepted answer.

Comment: Sometimes I ran into issues like 'everywhere it works but on mine'. So I upvote that comment of uninstalling the jQuerify extension. Haven't thought of that.

Comment: Niklas, I couldn't after my answer because of the 8 hour break between 2 posts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I found the "bug". I uninstalled the jQuerify extension for FireBug, and my popup is ok. Don't know why ... Thanks for your answer, really helps me !